# Hadoop streaming on AWS - Sentiment Analysis Example

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am doing the AWS Big data example: sentiment analysis using Hadoop streaming with Python code (link below:)

```
http://blog.newitfarmer.com/anls/analytics-bi/sentiment-analysis-analytics-bi/13436/repost-analyzing-big-data-getting-started-sentiment-analysis
```

Everything works fine "except that" the process fails because I cannot access the following key file for the example:

```
s3://awsdocs/gettingstarted/latest/sentiment/config–nltk.sh
```

I suspect the issue could be there is not public read access to this file..

Could someone advise me how to access this shell script file or how to copy it to my own folder? 
(I know the syntax for Amazon Machine instance unix copying is `s3cmd put *filename* *copylocation*`  but AMI's unix promt does not allow me to copy the copy the file)

***EDIT:***
OK, i have now come half way to the solution:
While I cannot still access the file I succeeded in copying the file to my own folder using the following command:

```
s3cmd cp s3://awsdocs/gettingstarted/latest/sentiment/config-nltk.sh s3://mysentimentjobX/
```

Now I should be able to put this file on my own folder and run the Hadoop streaming job from my own S3 bucket. I will let you know if I succeed with the last bit and tell you how I did it (if I succeed :) )

Answer (score -1):

(Moved from OP's question):

> It seems the name AWS gave this example script (config–nltk.sh) caused problems by using - rather than _. When I copied the file to my own S3 bucket renamed to use _ then I could run the example without any problem.